# Integration Inequality with Inner Products

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose $f: [1, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is continuous. Show that $(\int_{1}^{\infty}f)^{2} \leq \int_{1}^{\infty} x^{2}f(x)^{2}dx$

This problem is from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 4e (problem 6A.18).

So far, I've done the following:

- Considering the inner product $<f,g> = \int_{1}^{\infty}fg$, and multiplying both sides of the inequality by $\int_{1}^{\infty}1$, we get $\int_{1}^{\infty}1 (\int_{1}^{\infty}f)^{2}\leq ||xf||\cdot||1||$
- Using Cauchy-Schwarz and the fact $f$ is nonnegative: $\int_{1}^{\infty}f \leq \int_{1}^{\infty}xf = |<x,f>| \leq ||xf||\cdot||1||$

I got stuck here, as I don't really know how to combine these inequalities to solve the problem. I would be thankful for feedback about what I've done so far and hints on how to continue.

Thanks!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz says $\langle g,h\rangle^2 \le \langle g,g\rangle \langle h,h\rangle  $ so if we want to use this to get $\int_1^\infty x^2f(x)^2\mathrm{d}x = \langle xf(x),xf(x)\rangle$ on the RHS and $\int_1^\infty f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ on the LHS what could we choose for $g,h$?

Comment: @raj maybe $(\int f)^{2} \leq (\int xf)^{2} \leq \int 1 \int x^{2}f^{2}$, so $g = xf$ and $h = 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=\left(\frac1{x}\right)(xf(x))$.  Then, we
have

$$\begin{align}
\left(\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx\right)^2&=\left(\int_1^\infty \left(\frac1x\right)(xf(x))\,dx\right)^2\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz.